# How do I get my VPS to start using the extra disk space I purchased via HostMonster?

Tags: linux, centos, cpanel, whm, diskspace

My VPS is using centOS.  Through my hosting company I am provided cPanel and WHM.  I keep getting warning emails that my main disk is nearly full.  I was under the assumption that upgrading to more disk space would solve the problem, but this has not been the case.  What do I need to do so that my VPS will effectively make use of this extra space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend given partition.

1. Identify which partition to resize (check twice - mistake can cost you system failure)
2. Make backup :)
3. Resize this partition
4. Resize filesystem